# why struts resources bundle having myresource.properties and myresource_en.properties files

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, struts

struts having default resource properties "myresource.properties" and language resource properties "myresource_en.properties" but in real time in my project I have all English non-adaptation content in  "myresource.properties" file then why we need to use "myresource_en.properties" file.

Any one could you please explain the reason why struts having "myresource.properties" as default and "myresource_en.properties" for english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The _xx mentioned above stands for the country ISO code of the language you want to support. If you want to support English and German, you have to supply the files:

> myresource_de.properties (German)
>
> myresource_en.properties (English)
>
> myresource.properties (fallback for all other ISO codes)

Edit :

> myresource.properties (fallback for all other ISO codes)

this is used to hold for characters such as hexnumeric characers etc

Comment: Can you give me some example for ISO codes.... I have one more question where I need to keep my URL's

Comment: Consider searching google and or wikipedia.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_language_codes